# Merging tracks from multiple GPX files into a single track?

Tags: merge, gpx

I'd lke to merge multiple tracks from multiple GPS files into a *single track* in a single GPX file.

I tried the Merge option in Gps Track Editor and GPSBabel, to no avail: In both cases, I end up with multiple tracks in a single file.

This is what it looks like when uploading the merged file to eg. GPSVisualizer:

[image]

Is there a way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any way to perform that operation with .gpx files. If you have QGIS, however, you can save the .gpx as a shapefile and then perform a 'singlepart to multipart' (Similar to ArcMap's 'Dissolve') operation on the shapefile so that it contains only one feature. Then, save the shapefile as a .gpx, and it should then read as a single track.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for

```
gpsbabel -i gpx -f in.gpx -x track,trk2seg -o gpx -F out.gpx
```

From the documentation :

> **seg2trk option**
>
> Split track at segment boundaries into multiple tracks.
>
> This option splits tracks at segment boundaries into multiple tracks.
> This is useful to restore the behaviour of GPSBabel versions up to
> 1.3.6 which didn't support track segment markers and automatically put each segment into a separate track.
>
> **trk2seg option**
>
> Merge tracks inserting segment separators at boundaries.
>
> This option merges multiple tracks, inserting segment separators at
> track boundaries. It expects the tracks to already be in the right
> order for merging, i.e. it does not check timestamps and reorder track
> points so that their timestamps are monotonically increasing.

From this :

[image: From this]

I got this

[image: To This]

Answer (score 1):

Kind of late to answer this, but I have been working on a web tool that does exactly that:

https://gotoes.org/strava/Combine_GPX_TCX_FIT_Files.php

It can ingest GPX, TCX, and FIT files, and output the same.  You get various options, including the ability to repair points (you can drag them along a map).  Also, it can repair some types of corrupted FIT files that you upload.